# How to show image in image tag jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to append an image after every image tag to show share button. Here is the fiddler link http://jsfiddle.net/q98up2f3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    if($(this).prop('height')>100 && $(this).prop('width')>100) {
      $(this).addClass( "myClass" );
      $(this).wrapInner('<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/share-128.png" />');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.myclass:hover{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
  <img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/e4/f7/89/little-venice.jpg'>
  <img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/e4/f7/89/little-venice.jpg'>
  <img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/e4/f7/89/little-venice.jpg'>
</div>
```

Adding class dynamically.
while inspecting elements showing class and injected tag but its not reflecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See output below

use  after() function to insert after that particular item [see Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    if($(this).prop('height')>100 && $(this).prop('width')>100) {
      $(this).addClass( "myClass" );
      $(this).after('<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/share-128.png" />');
    }
    $('.myClass').hover(function(){
      $(this).next().show();    
    },function(){
      $(this).next().hide();    
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.myclass:hover{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
<img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/e4/f7/89/little-venice.jpg'>
<img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/e4/f7/89/little-venice.jpg'>
<img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/e4/f7/89/little-venice.jpg'>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi sir . Thank u very much for answer but still facing css issue new fid link jsfiddle.net/q98up2f3/3

Comment: @user1837779 whats your issue in this link?

Comment: on hover the css of other image is not changing ie display:none to display:block

Comment: @user1837779 if it works like what you want then edit the orignal question.

Comment: it will not change with css as it needs to be its parent element to change css of child when parent is hovered

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        if($(this).prop('height')>100 && $(this).prop('width')>100)
        {
            $(this).addClass( "myClass" );
            $('<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/share-128.png" />').insertAfter($(this));
        }

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q98up2f3/1/